# Is there a reason why git clone wouldn't work in windows but would work in Xubuntu?

Tags: linux, windows, git, github, clone

Tried to clone a remote repository

"git clone git@github.com:USER-NAME/REPOSITORY-NAME.git"

everything works fine in Xubuntu terminal but when I tried the same on windows with git bash it gives this error:

"Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository"

Using the same SSH key and everything, not sure what's going on.

Comment: The error suggests that you're *not* using the same ssh key in both environments (or that git in your Windows environment isn't aware of the ssh key). I'm not familiar with Windows so I can't really help on specifics, but the error clearly means that your Windows git isn't authenticating with the same credentials as your Xubuntu git.

Comment: Try debugging a regular ssh connection first: `ssh -vT git@github.com` will show what keys the ssh client tries and what the server replies. You may need to use `-i` to specify your key file if it's not offered by default. On Linux you can also configure this in `~/.ssh/config`, maybe there is a similar configuration file on Windows; check https://superuser.com/questions/1544120/ssh-config-file-for-windows-10s-ssh